# Xamarin Android OnBackPressed is not firing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this code on my MainActivity

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
   base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

I have set a break point on the `base.OnBackPressed()` which is not been executing. I have no clue why. When I press the back button the app exits like it's suppose too.

But it seems that I can't override the functionality of the hardware back button since the callback is not executing...

Any ideas on this?

Comment: That is the correct way to override it. If your breakpoint is not getting hit while debugging either that isn't the current activity or you might try deleting the bin and obj folders and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio "funny" things again.. I had to clear - rebuild the solution and now it's working. Thanks @Nick